# No .Minecraft folder at school

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Having already bought the game, I decided to download Minecraft so I could play it at school.
The game works fine and all, but, when I tried to add in a new texture pack, I discovered that there is no .minecraft folder.

When I clicked the 'open resource pack folder' button, this message popped up:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\97dpeterson\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\resourcepacks'.
>   Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Comment: Did you forget a \ between Roaming and .minecraft?

Comment: Isn't this against school rules?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `\` between `Roaming` and `.minecraft`. Your path should be:

```
C:\Users\97dpeterson\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks
```

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of the comment 3ventic made. Please be original, or don't post if its already been said.

Comment: @Chantola If you say so, just flag as low quality or downvote it. No need to lecture me over it.

Comment: I just don't want you to repeat this mistake again. If i just down-voted this post then you may never know why.

Comment: @Chantola is trying to improve your future answers and you tell him to flag and leave?

Comment: This answers the question. 3ventic should have posted it as an answer if they wanted the rep. The answer was obvious from the content of the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**you must edit the JavaScript file to allow access to %appdata% folder to allow access there, then make a .minecraft folder or download one and insert it to your "roaming" folder**